# SQL Server Transactions how can I commit my transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 stored procedure. Someone one is calling my stored procedure within a transaction. In my stored proc I'm logging some information (insert into a table). When the higher level transaction rolls back it removes my insert.

Is there anyway I can commit my insert and prevent the higher level rollback from removing my insert?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you start a new transaction, it will be nested within the outer transaction.  SQL Server guarantees that a rollback will result in an unmodified database state.  So there is no way you can insert a row inside an aborted transaction.

Here's a way around it, it's a bit of a trick.  Create a linked server with `rpc out = true` and `remote proc transaction promotion = false`.  The linked server can point to the same server as your procedure is running on.  Then, you can use `execte (<query>) at <server>` to execute something in a new transaction.

```
if OBJECT_ID('logs') is not null drop table logs
create table logs (id int primary key identity, msg varchar(max))
if OBJECT_ID('TestSp') is not null drop procedure TestSp
go
create procedure TestSp as
execute ('insert into dbo.logs (msg) values (''test message'')') at LINKEDSERVER
go
begin transaction
exec TestSp
rollback transaction
select top 10 * from logs
```

This will end with a row in the log table, even though the transaction was rolled back.

Here's example code to create such a linked server:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT srv.name FROM sys.servers srv WHERE srv.server_id != 0 AND 
        srv.name = N'LINKEDSERVER')
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'LINKEDSERVER', 
        @droplogins='droplogins'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LINKEDSERVER', 
    @srvproduct=N'LOCALHOST', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'LOCALHOST', 
    @catalog=N'DatabaseName'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINKEDSERVER', @optname=N'rpc out', 
     @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINKEDSERVER', 
    @useself=N'True', @locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL, @rmtpassword=NULL
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINKEDSERVER', 
    @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
```

Comment: @codingguy3000: Found a trick around it, answer edited.  This requires administrative privilege tho

Answer (score 3):

In `Oracle` you would use autonomous transactions for that, however, `SQL Server` does not support them.

It is possible to declare a table variable and return it from your stored procedure.

The table variables survive the `ROLLBACK`, however, the upper level code should be modified to read the variable and store its data permanently.

Comment: Just what I was going to suggest

Answer (score 2):

Depending on permissions, you could call out using xp_cmdshell to OSQL thereby creating an entirely separate connection. You might be able to do something similar with the CLR, although I've never tried it. However, I **strongly** advise against doing something like this.

Your best bet is to establish what the conventions are for your code and the calling code - what kind of a contract is supported between the two. You could make it a rule that your code is never called within another transaction (probably not a good idea) or you could give requirements on what the calling code is responsible for when an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Anything inside of a transaction will be part of that transaction. If you don't want it to be part of that transaction then do not put it inside.

Comment: The calling stored procedure is starting the transaction. So I have no way to avoid being part of this transaction.

Comment: Can you redesign how that works? It sounds like a poor design, in general